# MySQL SELECT while UPDATE

Tags: mysql, select, while-loop

I wrote a query, and Im sure that it was right form.
But I get an error. :)
May I do this query else?

```
UPDATE pages SET 
    p_name = 'Activites', 
    p_active = 1, 
    p_parent = 'sport', 
    p_parent_id=(
    SELECT p_id FROM pages WHERE p_link='sport' LIMIT 1
    ), 
    p_link = 'activites' 
    WHERE p_id = 9;
```

Thank you.

Comment: @devel: mysql doesn't support selecting from a table that you're updating/deleting at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that this way. You need to cross join the table and subquery:

```
UPDATE 
  pages AS p
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT p_id FROM pages WHERE p_link='sport' LIMIT 1
) AS sq
SET 
  p.p_name = 'Activites', 
  p.p_active = 1, 
  p.p_parent = 'sport', 
  p.p.parent_id= sq.p_id 
  p.p_link = 'activites' 
WHERE p.p_id = 9;
```

Comment: Its nice! :)
Thank you your fast answer.

Comment: @szatti1489: If it is nice, mark it as the answer by clicking the `Check/Correct`.